# Adding columns to database using fuelphp

Tags: fuelphp

I have added a new column in the model of a specific class.

```
'img'=>array(
    'data_type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Image',
    'default'=>null,
    'validation' => array(
        'trim'
    ),
),
```

How do i run the model to update the database? i assume i need to run some kind of script.

Comment: Didn't you mean column? Model definitions don't update your database. That's what migrations are for. Take a look at the [migrations' documentation](http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/migrations.html), and if you get stuck with that, come back, and update your question.

Comment: @BartaTamás so i do not run change the model file i change a migration file? what access on my server do i need to run the migrate?

Comment: It depends. If you have SSH access, you can run the migration script on your server, but if you only have an open port for MySQL, you can run it on your own dev machine (of course configuring the remote database, and using that configuration, when running the migrations). FuelPHP does not encourage the use of magic, it encourages you to design your database manually, and carefully, doing so by not depending on model definitions when creating the database, but running migration scripts.

Comment: @BartaTamás what is the deference between up() and down() funstions?

Comment: Your migrations represent versions of your database, and you can switch between them. `up()` and `down()` handles the changes between the versions, so if you're on revision 5, and want to get to 3, your 5th migrations `down()` is ran, and then the 4th's, so you get to 3. Similarly when you run `oil r migrate`, the `up()` of the migrations not yet ran will run. But these are much better explained in the documentation I linked earlier, you get full examples there. Happy Fueling! :)